# Partial update of JSON Object in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-json

Good afternoon,

When I try to update part of a JSON Object, using ON `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, how do you update a specific value with a key?

The code executes successfully but all values are updated when I just want the stock to change on update.

Any help would be welcomed, I am not convinced, I understand the MySQL JSON Path syntax, or perhaps JSON_SET cannot achieve my goal?

```
INSERT INTO table (name, attributes) VALUES
("Sarah", JSON_OBJECT('profile', "F", "el", "[4, 5, 6]")),
("John",  JSON_OBJECT('profile', "M", "el", "[10]"))
AS t
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  attributes = JSON_SET(t.attributes, '$.attributes.el',  '$.attributes.el')
                                                         # ^
                                                         # +--- value being inserted
```

I have also tried another flavour without success:

```
attributes = JSON_REPLACE(t.attributes, '$.t.el', "$.t.el")
```

Third attempt using wildcards and json extract, which replaces the entire JSON_OBJECT()

```
attributes = JSON_REPLACE(t.attributes, '$.t[2]', JSON_EXTRACT(t.attributes, "$.stock"))
```

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO with some initial sample data (3-5 rows). Specify needed actions. Show desired final data state after each separate action. Also provide precise MySQL version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need to use the [`VALUES` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) inside  `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement which gives you access to the value being inserted:

```
CREATE TABLE t(
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  attributes JSON
);

INSERT INTO t(name, attributes) VALUES
('Sarah', '{"profile": "F", "el": ["insrted", 1]}'),
('John',  '{"profile": "M", "el": ["insrted", 2]}');

-- insert + on duplicate (mysql 5.x)
INSERT INTO t(name, attributes) VALUES
('Sarah', '{"profile": "F", "el": ["dup_upd", 3]}'),
('John',  '{"profile": "M", "el": ["dup_upd", 4]}'),
('Jack',  '{"profile": "M", "el": ["insrted", 1]}')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE attributes =
    JSON_SET(attributes, '$.el', JSON_EXTRACT(VALUES(attributes), '$.el'));

-- insert + on duplicate (mysql 8.x)
INSERT INTO t(name, attributes) VALUES
('Sarah', '{"profile": "F", "el": ["dup_upd", 3]}'),
('John',  '{"profile": "M", "el": ["dup_upd", 4]}'),
('Jack',  '{"profile": "M", "el": ["insrted", 1]}')
AS t_ins
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE attributes =
    JSON_SET(t.attributes, '$.el', JSON_EXTRACT(t_ins.attributes, '$.el'));

SELECT name, JSON_PRETTY(attributes)
FROM t
```

```
name  | JSON_PRETTY(attributes)
------|-------------------------------------------
Sarah | {"el": ["dup_upd", 3], "profile": "F"}
John  | {"el": ["dup_upd", 4], "profile": "M"}
Jack  | {"el": ["insrted", 1], "profile": "M"}
```

[Demo on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e80e23a53cf234d5794701faf39e537b)

Comment: Great work on providing examples for differing MySQL versions, I am kicking myself that I failed to use JSON_SET(). Appreciate your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

the `JSON_EXTRACT` might help you extract the new value from the duplicate row being inserted.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (name, attributes) VALUES
  ("Sarah", JSON_OBJECT('profile', "F", "el",  "[4, 5, 6]" )),
  ("John", JSON_OBJECT('profile', "M", "el",  "[10]" ))
AS t ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
attributes = JSON_SET(table_name.attributes, '$.el', JSON_EXTRACT(t.attributes, '$.el'))
```

**Note** Aliasing the row being inserted using the `AS` keyword is only supported in MySQL version 8.x, In prior version you can refer to it using `VALUES` keyword.