# MYSQL - append new array elements to JSON column

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, sql-update

I have a table with json columns with default empty arrays [].

old table

| id | myJson |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | [1, 2] |
| A12 | [] |

I want the table updated to below.

| id | myJson |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | [1, 2, 321, 432] |
| A12 | [222] |

Tried - `INSERT INTO table (id, myJson) VALUES ("A1", "[321, 432]"), ("A12", "[222]") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE myJson = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(myJson, "$", myJson)`

Above query and other tried so far did not produce desirable result.

What query can i use to append new arrays to old as shown in the tables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL append json object to array of json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674489/mysql-append-json-object-to-array-of-json-objects)

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70083619/partial-update-of-json-object-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of MySQL are you using?

One option is to use [`JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-preserve) or [`JSON_MERGE_PATCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-patch) (as needed):

```sql
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `myJson`)
VALUES ('A1', '[321, 432]'), ('A12', '[222]') AS `new`
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `table`.`myJson` = JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(`table`.`myJson`, `new`.`myJson`);
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b3b04b36e6ed6b5aa50d858676072387).

Comment: Thanks. I Use version 8.0.28. It is producing error as I can't give alias to VALUES. 
`Unexpected token. (near "AS" at position 94)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "AS" at position 94)`

Comment: @Dare: Are you executing the statement from the MySQL command line (CLI) or another client (PHPMyAdmin, for example)?

Comment: Executing from PHPMyAdmin, using XAMPP

Comment: This eventually worked on my PHPMyAdmin   ` INSERT INTO table (id, myJson) VALUES ("A1", "[A321, 432]"), ("A12", "[222]") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE myJson = JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(myJson, VALUES(myJson)) `

Comment: @Dare: Possibly PHPMyAdmin has not yet implemented the change and therefore the error. See [MySQL 8.0.20 - INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements is now deprecated](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16167).